# How do you evenly distribute list with less length to another list?

Tags: python, algorithm, divide

I have two lists. The first one is named **location** and its length could vary from 1 to infinity.

```
location = ['loc1,'loc2','loc3','loc4,'loc5','loc6','loc7,'loc8','loc9','loc10,'loc11','loc12','loc13,'loc14','loc15','loc16,'loc17','loc18','loc19,'loc20','loc21','loc22,'loc23','loc24','loc25','loc26','loc27',] <- Please note that length could from 1 to infinite number
```

The second list is named **auditor** . It's length is usually greater than **location** list length. I want to evenly divide all the auditors to the locations if it is not even the first or last auditor be divided to additional location.

```
auditor = ['aone','atwo','athree','afour','afive','asix','aseven','aeight','anine','aten','aeleven','atwelve','athirteen','afourteen','afitheen','asixteen,'aseventeen''] <- Please note that length could from 1 to infinite number
```

The code below is working great for most cases but it is failing when location is 28 and auditor is 17

```
df2['location'] = location
df2['auditor'] = [auditor[int(df2)] for df2 in np.arange(0, len(auditor), (len(auditor)/len(df2)))]
```

My desired output is to get most possible even divided list, and it must work in every situation, as long as location is greater than auditor.

My_desired_output =
'aone',
'aone'
'atwo',
'atwo',
'athree',
'athree',
'afour',
'afour',
'afive',
'afive',
'asix',
'asix',
'aseven',
'aseven',
'aeight',
'aeight',
'anine',
'anine',
'aten',
'aten',
'aeleven',
'aeleven',
'atwelve',
'athirteen',
'afourteen',
'afifteen',
'asixteen',
'aseventeen']

Comment: In your example, location > auditors. The code shud work for <, =, >  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can consider using the `chunked` function found in `more-itertool`:

```py
from more_itertools import chunked
from math import ceil
from typing import List, Any, Tuple, Iterator


def distribute_evenly(items: List[Any], cells: List[Any]) -> Iterator[Tuple[Any, List[Any]]]:
    if len(items) <= len(cells):
        item_chunks = [[item] for item in items] + [[]] * (len(cells) - len(items))
    else:
        chunk_size = int(ceil(len(items) / len(cells)))
        item_chunks = chunked(auditor, chunk_size)
    
    return zip(cells, item_chunks)


location = ["loc1", "loc2", "loc3"]
auditor = ["aud1", "aud2", "aud3", "aud4", "aud5", "aud6", "aud7", "aud8"]


auditor_per_location = list(distribute_evenly(auditor, location))

# auditor_per_location is now [('loc1', ['aud1', 'aud2', 'aud3']), ('loc2', ['aud4', 'aud5', 'aud6']), ('loc3', ['aud7', 'aud8'])]
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for answer, the output is not what i am looking for. its a list of list

Comment: @Eegii what is your desired output?

Comment: What other output were you expecting?